# Use of ~ in R that does not refer to an equation (inside S4 class function)?

Tags: r, r-s4

Inside an S4 class function like this:

```
.groupVariants <- function(variants, indexOnly) {

extraCols <- if (indexOnly) character(0) else c("chromosome", "position", "ref","allele", "group_id")

groups <- unique(variants$group_id)

lapply(setNames(groups, groups), function(g) {

    filter_(variants, ~(group_id == g)) %>%

        select_(~(one_of(c("variant.id", extraCols, "allele.index"))))

})

}
```

What does the use of the tilde symbol mean in the lines

```
filter_(variants, ~(group_id == g))

select_(~(one_of(c("variant.id", extraCols, "allele.index"))))
```

and why are they needed?

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with S4. That's just the old-style syntax for dplyr non-standard evaluation. This syntax is being superseded by the new rlang style syntax.  It's not well documented or encouraged anymore. You can see some discussion of if there under the "non standard evaluation" section: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/select

Comment: Also this archived vignette is relevant https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.rdocumentation.org/rpackages/unarchived/dplyr/0.7.3/vignettes/nse.html